# Get a slice of json string from mongo using golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am trying to get a slice of json text from mongo using the below code in golang

```
var a []string
err := col..Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"_id": 0}).All(&a)
```

I get the error `Unsupported document type for unmarshalling: string`

**May I know the right way to do this?**

Comment: Every BSON document in MongoDB is, at its root, a BSON object (equivalent to a JSON object); it cannot possibly be a string. Take a look at your data - are you trying to extract a string *field* from the documents maybe?

Comment: @Adrian Want to store the resulting json as a text in a slice

Comment: You can't, because Mongo doesn't return JSON. It returns BSON. You'd need to unmarshal the BSON into memory and then marshal that back into JSON. Can you maybe offer up any details or context on what you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The thing is I dont know what type of json structure I would be getting from mongo which is why, I want to store the json in a slice of strings?

Comment: OK, but the thing still is MongoDB **does not operate in JSON, it operates in BSON, which is a binary format, not a text format**.

Comment: Time for a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select all but `_id`, the return will be a document containing only the remaining fields. You can do:

```
type fieldDoc struct {
  Field string `bson:"name"`
}
var a []fieldDoc
err := col.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"_id": 0}).All(&a)
```

If you don't know the underlying structure:

```
var a []bson.M
err := col.Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"_id": 0}).All(&a)
```

That should give you the documents encoded as bson objects. That is a map[string]interface{}, so you *should* be able to marshal it to JSON if you want json output:

```
jsonDocs, err:=json.Marshal(a)
```

Comment: What type is  `Field` here? Is it a string?

Comment: `string`, I guess, that's what you're trying to retrieve. I edited the answer.

Comment: The thing is I dont know what type of json structure I would be getting from mongo which is why, I want to store the json in a slice of strings? The above answer will just have empty strings in the slice I think

Comment: I edited the answer. That should give you a JSON string for the result set. If you want to store in an array of strings, you can iterate through `a` array and unmarshal each.